# Grouping content types in group nodes

Tags: views, group

I have created 2 different groups and updated content(basic pages & article) using group module in my drupal 8 project.

Currently it is listed in nodes tab of group.

I have used an view module to group based on the content type. But i couldn't make it.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module provides [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) 'relationships' to any node's parent group.

Try these steps to create your view:

- Add a relationship to the parent group.
- Add a contextual filter on the group's id (`gid`).
- Create a page, a block, a content pane, etc (whatever fits your needs).

Comment: Thanks pierre... also i tried for custom create link, if suppose in group of pages i need to add an custom create page link(global). I checked with views.  no option in it. Could you please help me?